# Cassandra ResultSet gets empty after traversing it once

Tags: python, json, serialization, cassandra

I have a python script that pulls data out of a database.  The problem is it is only pulling one item type and not the complete dataset into the JSON serialized object.

The object I'm trying to get comes from this:

```
STATS = ['min', 'max', 'mean','percentile1', 'percentile5', 'median', 'percentile95', 'percentile99', 'total']
```

The only problem is for some reason it will only ever take the first one.  It that example it was 'min'  if I switch the first to be 'percentile' such as this:

```
STATS = ['percentile1','min', 'max', 'mean',, 'percentile5', 'median', 'percentile95', 'percentile99', 'total']
```

Then this will load only the 'percentile' data. It is not including any of the rest.  It is querying the correct data with each one but will only pass the first one to the Rickshaw.js to draw the graphs.

I am serializing the data with this:

```
def get_series(self, stationid, metric, monthly=True):
    '''
    Format results into json-ready results for Rickshaw.js.
    '''

    allResults = {}
    if monthly:
        rs = self.get_monthly_report(stationid, metric)
    else:
        rs = self.get_daily_report(stationid, metric)
    for field in STATS:
        series = self.format_series(rs, field)
        allResults[field] = series
    return json.dumps(allResults,  default=json_serial)

def format_series(self, records, field):
    '''
    JSON formatting helper.
    '''

    data = []
    for record in records:
        data.append({'x' : time.mktime(record['date'].timetuple()), 'y' :    record[field]})
    return data
```

If you need more of the code. I can gladly provide. Thank you!

I inserted some print commands

```
def get_series(self, stationid, metric, monthly=True):
        '''
        Format results into json-ready results for Rickshaw.js.
        '''

        allResults = {}
        if monthly:
            rs = self.get_monthly_report(stationid, metric)
        else:
            rs = self.get_daily_report(stationid, metric)
        for field in STATS:
            print "The field is"
            print (field)
            series = self.format_series(rs, field)
            print "The Series is"
            print (series)
            allResults[field] = series
        return json.dumps(allResults,  default=json_serial)
```

this is what appears:

```
The field is
min
The Series is
[{'y': 0, 'x': 1388552400.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1391230800.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1393650000.0}, {'y': 19, 'x': 1396324800.0}, {'y': 52, 'x': 1398916800.0}, {'y': 13, 'x': 1401595200.0}, {'y': 37, 'x': 1404187200.0}, {'y': 10, 'x': 1406865600.0}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1409544000.0}, {'y': 49, 'x': 1412136000.0}, {'y': 28, 'x': 1414814400.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1417410000.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1420088400.0}, {'y': 46, 'x': 1422766800.0}, {'y': 60, 'x': 1425186000.0}, {'y': 52, 'x': 1427860800.0}, {'y': 58, 'x': 1430452800.0}, {'y': 69, 'x': 1433131200.0}, {'y': 48, 'x': 1435723200.0}, {'y': 20, 'x': 1438401600.0}, {'y': 22, 'x': 1441080000.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1443672000.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1446350400.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1448946000.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1451624400.0}, {'y': 10, 'x': 1454302800.0}, {'y': 48, 'x': 1456808400.0}, {'y': 66, 'x': 1459483200.0}, {'y': 60, 'x': 1462075200.0}, {'y': 58, 'x': 1464753600.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1467345600.0}, {'y': 17, 'x': 1470024000.0}, {'y': 27, 'x': 1472702400.0}, {'y': 31, 'x': 1475294400.0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1477972800.0}, {'y': 10, 'x': 1480568400.0}, {'y': 65, 'x': 1483246800.0}]
The field is
max
The Series is
[]
The field is
mean
The Series is
[]
The field is
percentile1
The Series is
[]
The field is
percentile5
The Series is
[]
The field is
median
The Series is
[]
The field is
percentile95
The Series is
[]
The field is
percentile99
The Series is
[]
The field is
total
The Series is
[]
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying that format_series isn't working properly? Or is it get_series() that returns an unexpected result?

Comment: The data that appears to be returned is only for the very first item in the "STATS" variable. I need for it to show all of them.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? What is the function, or line of code, that returns only part of the data? Is it format_series?

Comment: the format_series is only returning the first item in the STATS variable.  If i change the first item in the stats variable it then shows only that item.  So for some reason it is not adding all items into the array to be serialized and returned.

Comment: Could you insert a print of field before the line "series = ..." and a print of the series just afterwards, and send the output?

Comment: ok I did that and this is what it outputs:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100408/discussion-between-mithrix-and-adi-levin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of get_month_report is of type

```
<cassandra.cluster.ResultSet object at 0x7fe1a6b6e910>
```

so when you traverse it once it depletes. You need to turn it to a list before traversing it multiple times, by the "list" operator:

```
 if monthly:
   rs = list(self.get_monthly_report(stationid, metric))
 else:
   rs = list(self.get_daily_report(stationid, metric))
```